# SQL ORDER BY подскажите как отсортировать по нескольким условиям

Tags: sql, postgresql

Доброго времени суток

подскажите как отсортировать по нескольким условиям (SQL ORDER BY )

допустим таблица

A(row_num) B(аттрибут),C(name)

нужна, сортировка по алфавиту по столбцу 'С'(имени), но так чтобы чтобы первыми были записи те, где B = null(а может не только null, а какой либо еще параметр должен быть приоритетным)

база postgresql

```
 условно должно выйти:

1  null   Петя           --идет раньше Андрея т.к. null
2  33     Андрей
3  20     Петр
4  454    Яна
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from table
order by case when attr is null then 0 else 1 end, name
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tbl
ORDER BY
  attr IS NOT NULL,
  name
```

Comment: век живи - век учись

Comment: получается что будет сортироваться по attr, а затем по name, внутри одинаковых attr?

Comment: @nonament, да. Нужна другая логика?

Comment: да, нужно имя взять за основу сортировки, кроме одного НО: позиций где attr null - должны быть первее

Comment: @nonament, тогда нужно поменять местами столбцы в ORDER BY. Поправил ответ.

Comment: перемена мест не поможет, будет алфавитный порядок для всех, а нужны условно 2 группы, первыми те кто null со своей сортировкой по алфавиту, затем все остальный - со своей сортировкой, в принципе соседний ответ с union-ми это демонстрирует, но нет ли более элегантного способа?)

Comment: @nonament, первоначальный запрос именно так и поступает, он разбивает записи таблицы на две группы NULL  и NOT NULL, далее в рамках каждой группы сортировка идет уже по алфавиту. Вернул первоначальный запрос.

Comment: Вау) подумать не мог, тогда попробую, спасибо, ...блин, можно было и case-ом разбить на 2 группы))

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE B IS NULL order by C) t1
union ALL
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE NOT B IS NULL order by C) t2
```

Comment: Громоздко получится, учитывая что у меня это внутри rank() over  PARTITION BY over... и бал бла с кучей условий,  гарантирует ли union сохранности порядка?

Comment: @nonament хороший вопрос. Думаю да, почему бы он должен его поломать?

Comment: не доверяю я запросам без order by в конце,  если нужна четка последовательность которую нужно передать на вышестоящие запросы) если больше ничего не придет в голову. то попробую добавить row_numer в оба юниона, второй продолжит там, где закончится первый

Comment: @nonament это не конструктивно. union склеивает две отсортированные выборки, с какого перепуга он должен их перемешать?